# MongoDB: Normalized Store to Embedded Domain Model

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have determined a relational model makes more sense for a particular collection in a database. The problem is, the domain model was originally started with an embedded model and there is a large amount of UI code that expects it to be in this form. Updating the database schema isn't an issue, but I'm curious if there is any easy way around remodeling the C# domain objects to a more old-fashioned relational model. I've started writing mappers (with AutoMapper) between version one and version two (see classes below), but it's getting messy really quick.

Below is some fictitious code that outlines a similar domain model.

```
// Existing
class MyClass
{
    List<Event> Events { get; set; }
    List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}

// How it should have been modeled
class MyClass
{
    List<int> Events { get; set; } // Stores Event IDs
    List<int> Movies { get; set; } // Stores Movie IDs
}
```

The database will have to be normalized.

If I have to remodel the domain model, that's fine; I just want to feel comfortable I've exhausted other possibilities that might save time. Is there an easy solution to this problem I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the specific problem, it seemed the only two options I could justify were the two I mentioned in my initial post (map the data manually or change my domain object). Ultimately, for me, the path of least resistance was to map the data manually. I appreciate the [suggestion by pjvds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966672/mongodb-normalized-store-to-embedded-domain-model/8035945#8035945), but I couldn't justify switching to a new ORM at this stage of the project considering so many other things work better with the C# MongoDB driver and also considering a mapper isn't necessary for the other portions of our database.

Answer (score 1):

If the only purpose of your restructuring is the relational database I'd advise you to look into [O/R mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). An O/R mapper, like [NHibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateForNET) or the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), should be able to map your existing *embedded model* to a relational database. Using an O/R mapper can take away the need of remodeling your domain.

Comment: This isn't a bad idea, I just didn't want to use an ORM for the purpose of mapping one very small piece of the entire database --especially considering we've used the C# MongoDB driver for everything else.